# How to properly zoom into a picture using scroll view without image flying to a random side

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I managed to pinch zoom into a `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` but the image leaves to the side or bottom such that I cannot scroll through the whole image in a zoomed in mode.

Tried playing around with the `constraints`, seems to have no effect.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PhotoZoomController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton!

    weak var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        assert(imageView != nil)
        if let iv = imageView {
            iv.image = image
        }
        scroller.delegate = self
    }


    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding `ZoomScale`.

```
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0 // Minimum zoom scale
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0 // Maximum zoom scale
scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0 //Default zoom scale
```

Hope this code works for you.

Comment: that does not fix it.

Comment: When I zoom in, the bottom of the image cannot be scrolled into view.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, first bound the imageview in storyboard to the 4 edges of scrollview with 0 spacing, then add a constraint for horizonal/vertical middle positioning.

After that include:

```swift
self.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
scroller.contentSize = imageView?.image?.size ?? scroller.contentSize
```

here is the whole file:

```swift
//
//  PhotoZoomController.swift
//
//
//  Created by John Karasev on 4/04/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 John Karasev. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class PhotoZoomController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    weak var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assert(imageView != nil)
        if let iv = imageView {
            iv.image = image
        }
        scroller.delegate = self
        scroller.zoomScale = 1.0
        scroller.addSubview(imageView!)
        self.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        scroller.contentSize = imageView?.image?.size ?? scroller.contentSize
    }


    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }


}
```